# ExecJS coffee script not showing line numbers for compile errors (Rails asset pipeline)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, asset-pipeline, execjs

In one of my Rails apps, ExecJS is not showing line numbers for coffeescript compilation errors. My compile error message will look like this:

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError in Referrals#new

Showing ~/MyApp/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

SyntaxError: unexpected IDENTIFIER
  (in ~/MyApp/assets/javascripts/utils.js.coffee)
```

Note that there's no line number for the coffee script source (line #6 is for the erb file).

On another one of my apps, where I'm still getting the line numbers, a syntax error looks like this:

```
ExecJS::ProgramError in Projects#show

Showing ~/OtherApp/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where     line #17 raised:

Error: Parse error on line 6: Unexpected 'STRING'
(in ~/OtherApp/app/assets/javascripts/projects.js.coffee)
```

So it seems the difference is that `ExecJS::ProgramError` will give me the line numbers, where as `ExecJS::RuntimeError` will not.

Anyone have any idea how to get the line numbers back? Why is my app creating RuntimeErrors  on coffee asset compilation, while the other is giving ProgramErrors? I've checked Rails and they seem to match.

Note that if I fix the compilation errors, the app runs fine (e.g., the coffee files are actually do get compiled) -- but it'd be nice to have those line numbers point me to the compilation errors!.

**EDIT**
I realized that whether it's an ExecJS `Runtimeerror` or a `ProgramError` doesn't seem to matter -- in the first app, there's never a line number given and in the second, there always is.

Comment: I'm on 1.6.2 and I'm getting this issue.

Comment: @Narfanator did you see my answer?

Comment: Yeah; it took me a minute; I set mine to 1.5.0 as well and it's good now. I'm surprised that functionality was lost; it's pretty core to development.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I figured it out -- it's due to the `coffee-script-source` gem version. In the app that was giving line numbers, `bundle show` gives coffee-script-source of 1.4.0, whereas the other app had a coffee-script-source version of 1.6.1.

I didn't notice this because the `coffee-rails` gem doesn't tightly specify this dependency (in both my Gemfiles, I was using `gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2'`). **To get around this, just explicitly specify the coffee-script-source gem version**:

```
gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.5.0'
```

and `bundle update coffee-script-source`.

Hopefully this helps anyone else who might run into this discrepancy.

Comment: It's weird how the newer version is worse

Comment: I'm using 1.6.3, there are no line numbers, it's basically useless. I've switched to using the binary provided by the node installation of coffeescript

Answer (score 2):

This can also be fixed with [this patch that embeds the line information in the error message](https://github.com/josh/ruby-coffee-script/pull/21) for the `ruby-coffee-script` gem.

If you're using source maps, [this patch](https://github.com/markbates/coffee-rails-source-maps/pull/16) fixes the `coffee-rails-source-maps` gem.