# Better errors gem not showing code on right hand side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, better-errors-gem

I am using better_errors gem   https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors   , but can't seem to get a critical piece of the gem working.

The stack trace shows, but the code snippets don't show in the browser. Clicking on the stack trace items only links me to the same page.

I am using windows 7 and 
`coffee-rails (4.0.1)`
`coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)`
`coffee-script-source (1.7.0)`

[image]

Comment: do you use coffeescript? which version?

Comment: `coffee-rails (4.0.1)`
`coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)`
`coffee-script-source (1.7.0)`

Comment: try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369614/execjs-coffee-script-not-showing-line-numbers-for-compile-errors-rails-asset-pi